# Will Daedalus have a Fiat payment gateway?

Tags: wallet, daedalus, trust

I am a rookie at cryptocurrencies: I would like to know if Daedalus will have a Fiat payment gateway. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I would love for this to happen. It will go a very long way for adoption and ease of use.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing specific apart from the fact that in one of Charles' interviews (I cannot find it at the moment) he mentioned that after there are DEXs and other components it will be very easy to add additional functionalities including easier ways to pay and convert crypto for fiat and vise versa.

Charles also [spoke in 2020](https://youtu.be/6pQzQbVgX7c?t=3316) about adding the functionality which now is available to get the current price from CoinGecko.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've heard rumors for just this; although I'm not turning up anything now. However, according to [this](https://forum.cardano.org/t/buying-ada-from-daedalus-wallet/53595) the Yoroi Chrome extension provides this functionality. But I wouldn't know, I don't use in-browser Yoroi.