# Will there ever be a fiat on-off ramp in the official wallets?

Tags: wallet

Will we ever have to and from fiat conversion available in the wallet? This would go a very long way in adopting and using Cardano. Currently, using exchanges is a rip-off in fees and  a headache in KYC-AML rules, plus maximum daily/weekly withdrawal limits are the worst.

If we could easily convert ADA to/from USD and EUR, that would be a game changer for many people.
I suppose second best thing would be a trusted, high liquidity DEX that offers fiat on/off ramps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this question: [Will Daedalus have a Fiat payment gateway?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/q/911/1142)

In short: There's no official information on the topic yet, but a DEX related solution might be implemented some time in the future.